# for loop in increments on r

Tags: r, for-loop

Hello.

 Need some assistance in building a for loop (or any other kind of loop if better?) that takes a vector of x values (named ticker) and runs it in an increment of 10 through a function which is then bounded to a data frame.

```
for(x in ticker){
  df1 = myfunction(ticker[1:10])
  df2 = myfunction(ticker[11:20])
  
  finaldf = bind_rows(df1,df2)
}
```

This example is clearly not in any loop format, as idk what I'm doing, but it's sorta what I'm getting at.

 The length of the vector will vary in the thousands. Thanks!

Comment: It is really not clear what you want

Comment: Do you need something like `data.frame(matrix(ticker, ncol=10))`?

Comment: No. I am using a function that queries data from an API but has a limit on the number of rows I can pull (estimate I can pull 10 tickers at once). I need to pull data for thousands of tickers from a vector called, ticker. I think there's a better approach to pulling data and binding the rows into a data frame than me typing out [1:10] to 4000 tickers or something.

Comment: You may need to share code for your API-function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split every 10 `ticker` values and apply `myfunction` to each group using `map_df`.

```
result <- purrr::map_df(split(ticker, rep(seq_along(ticker), 
           each = 10, length.out = length(ticker))), myfunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
set.seed(123)

vec <- sample(1000:10000, size = 40, replace = TRUE)

> vec
 [1] 3462 3510 9717 3985 2841 4370 5760 7745 3756 6106 3887 7169 3566 3979 2613 1554 5468 8788 2046 8066 4003 4206 8988 4994
[25] 9357 1216 9156 7215 9779 2598 5236 4936 5088 3906 1293 9468 1040 9507 8390 7671
```

Now iterate over every 10, do some function (in this case, divide by ten) to that slice and then re-combine:

```
out <- do.call(c, lapply(seq(1, length(vec), 10), function(i) {
  current_slice = vec[i:(i + 9)]
  print(paste0("Current slice: ", paste(current_slice, collapse = " "), sep  = ""))
  return(current_slice / 10)
}))

> out <- do.call(c, lapply(seq(1, length(vec), 10), function(i) {
+   current_slice = vec[i:(i + 9)]
+   print(paste0("Current slice: ", paste(current_slice, collapse = " "), sep  = ""))
+   return(current_slice / 10)
+ }))
[1] "Current slice: 3462 3510 9717 3985 2841 4370 5760 7745 3756 6106"
[1] "Current slice: 3887 7169 3566 3979 2613 1554 5468 8788 2046 8066"
[1] "Current slice: 4003 4206 8988 4994 9357 1216 9156 7215 9779 2598"
[1] "Current slice: 5236 4936 5088 3906 1293 9468 1040 9507 8390 7671"
```

Out:

```
> out
 [1] 346.2 351.0 971.7 398.5 284.1 437.0 576.0 774.5 375.6 610.6 388.7 716.9 356.6 397.9 261.3 155.4 546.8 878.8 204.6 806.6
[21] 400.3 420.6 898.8 499.4 935.7 121.6 915.6 721.5 977.9 259.8 523.6 493.6 508.8 390.6 129.3 946.8 104.0 950.7 839.0 767.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a function  that would loop through chunks of 10 elements from the vector for every iteration:

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
ticker<-sample(1:4000)
```

**code**

```
get_chuncks_of_ticker<-function(ticker){
        output<-vector('list', length(ticker)/10)
for (i in 1:(length(ticker)/10)){
        output[[i]]<-ticker[10*(i-1)+1:10]
        names(output)[[i]]<-paste0('column', i)
}
        tibble(cbind.data.frame(output))
}

final_data<-get_chunks_of_ticker(ticker)
head(final_data)

# A tibble: 6 x 400
  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11 column12
    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1    1017    3379    1749    3673    3476    3756    1304    1395     843       84      557     1522
2    3908     597      37     975    1948     537    1696    2547     465     1895     1685      858
3     679    1301    1129    2849    2580    2423     526    1128     996     3101      287     1840
4    2177    3946     729    2900    1530     248    2690    3398    1549     1165     2662     2667
5     930    1974     878    2979    2604    1222    1069     983    3880     2300     3217      576
6    1533    3566     485    2374    2937    2426    1426    1791    3801     2781     2377      990
```